# use of undeclared identifier searchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

When i invoke the searchBar object into the UISearchBar delegate methods like this, it works fine:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"You have taped:%@",searchBar.text);
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;

}
```

However, when i try to use it into another method from my own, i got that error:

```
use of undeclared identifier searchBar
```

I don't know why and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you don't have the searchBar variable defined. You'll need to create a member variable, probably as an IBOutlet so you can use it outside the scope of that function.

Answer (score 1):

`searchBar` is passed in to that method. If you try to use `searchBar` outside of that method and it is not declared then you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually passing a reference to a valid "searchBar" in to the message? The Interface will pass in a valid reference from your view for that parameter. It seems to me you should probably have a synthesized IBOutlet property for a UISearchBar in your code, pass that in to your message and you should be fine.